# Customizing math symbol "evaluated at" - Vertical bar growing up only below

Tags: math-mode, symbols, delimiters

I'd like to customize the math symbol "evaluated at".
If I use the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\frac{d}{dt} \left( i_{O_L} \Bigr|_{O_G} \right) =
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\frac{d}{dt} \left( i_{O_L} \Bigg\rvert_{O_G} \right) =
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

In the first case the vertical bar is too small.
In the second case the vertical bar grows up in both directions up and down. I'm wondering if it's possible to grow up the bar only below. For example (i want a thin vertical bar, in fugure it is not so thin):

[image]

---

EDIT:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Your notations look strange.What's evaluated? The derivative or the argument of the differential symbol?

Comment: Hello @Bernard see the edit please. I want only the symbol evaluated at like the above one.

Comment: So inside the parentheses?

Comment: ...like in the figure. Without parentheses.

Comment: Ps: if there is the option to put the above expression inside paretheses, it would be better.

Comment: But your images are not directly related to your code.

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/458265/4427 help?

Comment: Hello @egreg, in your link the vertical bar is not long as in my case and, if you take the imaginary horizontal midline in correspondence of the mathematical formula (in your link), you can see that the above half vertical bar is equal to the below half vertical bar. Instead in my case the vertical bar is long only in the below direction.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Not at all. The rule is longer in the lower part than in the upper part. I warn you that the longer is the lower part, the higher will be delimiters around it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not too sure I've well ubderstood what you want, but I propose this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{diffcoeff, array, delarray}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\diffp*{\begin{array}[t]({@{}c@{\,}|@{\,}c@{}})O_L & \\ & O_T\end{array}}{t}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\diffp*{\begin{array}[t]({@{}c@{\,}|@{\,}c@{}})O_L & \\[2ex] & O_T\end{array}}{t}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Bernard, I'm looking for a different style. Please see my figures (with and without d/dt). My vertical bar is long only in the below direction. I want to customize its length.

Comment: I've added another example to show how to modify the length of the vertical rule (downwards).

Comment: Excellent solution @Bernard.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a modification of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/458265/4427 where the rule only extends from the formula axis down, with a very large amount just for demonstration purposes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\evalat}[2]{\mathpalette\eval@at{{#1}{#2}}}
\newcommand{\eval@at}[2]{\eval@@at#1#2}
\newcommand{\eval@@at}[3]{%
  #2\,
  {%
   \sbox0{$#1\left|#2\right|$}%
   \vrule height \fontdimen22\textfont2 depth \dimexpr\dp0+5ex\relax
  }_{\,#3}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\evalat{x}{x=5}
\qquad
\evalat{\frac{x+1}{x-1}}{x=2}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Fix the depth by changing the value `5ex` to something more sensible. Be advised that delimiters using `\left` and `\right` will grow as much in the upper as in the lower direction.

Comment: Hi @egreg, thank you very much for your solution.